# Episerver add new virtual string textbox after its filled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, episerver

I just started learning Episerver and I have a block with 3 Textboxes(virtual string) when I add something to them the data gets displayed in a table in the view. I would like to fill the table with more data with the same method but since the added value is binded to the textbox I don't know what to do from there. I either want the textboxes to be empty after postback or that new textboxes gets added dynamically.

Code is simple enough so far.

From BlockType:

```
    public virtual string Namn { get; set; }

    public virtual string Innehåll { get; set; }

    public virtual int Pris { get; set; }
```

From View:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Namn</th>
        <th>Innehåll</th>
        <th>Pris</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td @Html.EditAttributes(x => x.Namn)>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Namn)</td>
        <td @Html.EditAttributes(x => x.Innehåll)>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Innehåll)</td>
        <td @Html.EditAttributes(x => x.Pris)>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Pris)Kr</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, for semantic reasons you shouldn't use åäö in your string names.

What you are trying to do wont work, even if there are ways to create lists using properties like this I cannot recommend it since they would be line based. It is a horrible practice.

I'd suggest that you use a simpler approach instead and wrap the table in a content area

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Namn</th>
        <th>Innehåll</th>
        <th>Pris</th>
    </tr>
    @Html.PropertyFor(x => x.YourContentArea)
</table>
```

Simplify your block a bit

Rename the properties for the sake of world peace

```
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual string Content { get; set; }
public virtual int Price { get; set; }
```

Replace the table with this row in the block view

```
<tr>    
    <td @Html.EditAttributes(x => x.Name)>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)</td>
    <td @Html.EditAttributes(x => x.Content)>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Content)</td>
    <td @Html.EditAttributes(x => x.Price)>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Price)Kr</td>
</tr>
```

All you have to do is to create one block instance and drag it into the content area that wraps the table.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Maybe I'm just a bit stupid but I'm having trouble understanding it? :/ Could you elaborate alittle bit more? Thanks!